# Caling procedure in conversion.asm from main .asm

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I have two asm files, one is conversion.asm and one is main.asm, I am using conversion.asm in main.asm. I am using floating point stack but I am not getting the right output.

main.asm

```
Include conversion.asm

.386
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
Cel DD 25
Faren DD ?

.code
main PROC
  push dword ptr Cel
  fld dword ptr [esp]

  call C2F

  fstp dword ptr [Faren]
  mov ebx, [Faren]
  INVOKE ExitProcess, ebx
main ENDP
END main
```

conversion.asm

```
.model flat, stdcall

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
.stack 4096

.data 
Cfirst DD 2
Csecond DD 1
common DD 32

C2F PROC
    push dword ptr Cfirst
    fld dword ptr [esp]
    add esp,4
    fmulp
    sub esp,4
    push dword ptr Csecond
    fld dword ptr [esp]
    add esp,4
    fdivp
    sub esp,4
    push dword ptr common
    fld dword ptr [esp]
    add esp,4
    faddp
    sub esp,4
    RET
C2F ENDP
```

Please help me out

Comment: Note that the exit code is an integer and you are returning a float. Maybe you wanted `fistp`? Also your conversion constants are stored as integers but you load floats. `dword` does not make it an integer it's just a size specifier. You need to use the integer mnemonics, with the `i` in the name usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fmul, fdiv, fadd edit data in floating stack directly, so instead of pulling from stack to register, do operation directly in floating stack.

Correct usage of floating point stack in conversion.asm:

```
.DATA
five DWORD 5.0
nine DWORD 9.0
ttw DWORD 32.0

.CODE
C2F proc
    fmul nine
    fdiv five
    fadd ttw
    ret
C2F ENDP
```

For reading float and writing float I used Irvine library, which uses floating point stack:

```
Include Irvine32.inc
Include conversion.asm

.data
Celprompt BYTE "Enter a value in C:",0
Cel DWORD 0
Resprompt BYTE "In Farenheit that value is - "
Faren DD ?

.code
main PROC
  mov edx, OFFSET Celprompt
  call WriteString
  call Crlf
  call ReadFloat
  call C2F
  call Crlf
  mov edx, OFFSET Resprompt
  call WriteString
  call WriteFloat
main ENDP
END main
```